# Raspberry Pi 3 + official touchscreen display app just shows black screen on DP6

Tags: android-things

I've connected the [offical touchscreen display](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/) via DSI to my Raspberry Pi 3 running the latest Android Things developer preview.

While booting the android things logo shows up and afterwards the new DP6 settings appear just fine.
When I install an app via adb the screen stays black and no suspicious log message shows up.
In DP 5.1 I had no problems with this.

Also tried running this example:
https://github.com/androidthings/sample-simpleui

Furthermore maxing out the screen brightness with the [ScreenManager](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/device/ScreenManager.html) didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Reflashing the image with the [Android Things Setup Utility](https://partner.android.com/things/console/#/tools) fixed my issue.